# Enable/disable button with if condtion in Data-Bind? knockoutjs

Tags: jquery, html, knockout.js

I am pretty new to knockout and need some help. I have form which will be loaded when I click on NEW button and it will be also loaded from some listing page when I click on user name in listing page(dataTable).

What I need is looks pretty basic and straight forward.

**Scenario 1 :** When I am coming from NEW button I need to fill all fields and then I have to save(button) which will in enabled state where I am also having NEXT STAGE BUTTON which is disabled  But on successful save it need to get enabled and so I can go to next stage/page.

**Scenario 2 :** Well this is were I am facing trouble to sort things. When I come from some listing page when I click on username link The data will be autofilled in form and now I have to make my NEXT STAGE button enable upfront on load just because it is already a saved form.

What I tried so far:

```
<button id="btnSave" class="btn" data-bind="click:$data.save">SAVE</button>
<input type ="button"  id="nextstage" data-bind="click:$root.nextstage,enable:false" value="NEXT STAGE"/>
```

I am also trying to achieve using **IF condition** in data-bind where I have absolutely no clue how to.

**My idea :** In data-bind I will enable/disable NEXTSTAGE based on the **field** on my form like example if I am having something like this

```
<input type="text"  id="txtComepitors" data-bind="value:$data.Competitors"/>
```

On my page load if the textbox is empty I will DISABLE if it is not I will enable. So I just need **if condition** to enable/disable nextstage in data-bind.

That's all I have and thought of it sadly lacks proper implementation.

Comment: Could you please share your full `html` and `javascript` code and we help, http://jsfiddle.net/ will be ideally :)

Comment: i would love to but it time consuming and i want just a logic like if x has value then button should be enabled if x have nothing button should be disabled :) just like that .

Comment: @supercool: I understand your sentiment. But if you want people to spend time on an answer, you might at least be willing to spend time on the question.

Comment: i agree with you :) cheers i take you suggestions . i will use computed and let you know :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's really hard to get from your question *exactly* what you are asking, but the cleanest way to do this would be with a `computed` observable.

So somewhere in your view model you'd have something like this:

```
self.canSave = ko.computed(function() {
    // test conditions for saving here (i.e. whether all the fields have values)
    // and return true if you can save
    // for example:
    return self.someProperty() && self.someOtherProperty();
});
```

Now you can use the enable binding like so:

```
<input type="button" value="Save Me!" data-bind="enable: canSave" />
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dk8Fv/) to demonstrate. Notice how the save button is grayed out until both text boxes have some value.

You can make the logic in your `computed` as complicated as you need and knockout will keep track of the dependencies and reevaluate it whenever one of the dependent observables changes. This keeps the VM logic from cluttering up your view.

Comment: yeah tought so but been so lazy and thinking about IF condtion in data-bind . sorry for being unclear with my question . appreciate your help

Comment: `If` conditions have their uses too, but the difference is that an `If` condition, if it evaluates to false, will actually remove the DOM elements inside it. So it won't disable, it'll disappear altogether. And if your test is more complicated that just testing a single value for "truthiness", you should probably use a `computed` anyway.

Comment: Mate well everything works cool but under save button(on  successful save) i have to make nextstage button enable . As of now present data-bind with computed is not enabling . any ideas

Comment: @supercool: Again, without more of your code, I'm mostly guessing. But my guess would be that you should add a `canNextStage` property, which could just be a regular `ko.observable` and bind `enable` on the next stage button to it. Then in your save function, after a successful save, just update `canNextStage` to `true`.

Comment: he he so so sorry and i done that . yes i just need to use self.nextstage(true) in my success :) cheers . sorry for troubling you and ty so so much for your patience and help